# Matplotlib StopIteration Exception

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, scatter-plot, jupyter-lab

I am plotting using a `for` loop in Jupyter-Lab. However, I keep getting `StopIteration` exception after the 10th plot. Any idea why?

```
for i in range(0,14):
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(y=y, x=X[:,0], color=next(colors), marker='.', label="")
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.title("")
    plt.xlabel("Feature")
    plt.ylabel("Response")
    plt.show()
```

`StopIteration:` 
`<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>`

Comment: You might want to provide a [mcve] to obtain help here.

Comment: Did you mean `x=X[:, i]`?

Comment: I went back to reproduce the problem and put up a full example when I realized the problem was nothing but the `color=next(colors)`. Since `colors` was `colors = iter(['yellowgreen', 'dodgerblue', 'red', 'm', 'gold', 'black', 'c', 'purple', 'orange', 'maroon'])` with only 10 colors; it would raise `StopIteration` and stop the `for loop`. Thank you for your suggestions and request of a full example.